# How can I convert a "key: value" sequence into JSON?

Tags: bash, key-value, jq

hokay, I am trying to write a script that takes information from the `yum - repolist all` and puts it into pretty JSON for me to use in some data collecting.. Right now I have my output from the yum command looking like this.

All I have for code right now is just the yum repolist command.

`#!/bin/bash -x
yum -v repolist all | grep -B2 -A6 "enabled" | sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' , 's/--//g' , 's/name=name=/name=/g'`

the output from that command looks like:

```
Repo-id: wazuh_repo
Repo-name: Wazuhrepository
Repo-status: enabled
Repo-revision: 1536348945
Repo-updated: FriSep712:35:512018
Repo-pkgs: 73
Repo-size: 920M
Repo-baseurl: https://packages.wazuh.com/3.x/yum/
Repo-expire: 21,600second(s)(last:WedOct3108:59:002018)
```

There are about 8 entries and the titles are always the same... Can someone explain like I am five how to convert this into json, I've read the jq man page, I've read about hash's. nothing seems to make sense. I know I need to have a "key"/"value" how to I designate these?

I just want to take the output and make it look like pretty JSON, this is part of a larger script I am writing to help keep ontop of the repos we use at work. I am just totally not getting JSON though.

edit: I would prefer not to use a wrapper function and do/learn the proper way

Comment: It's hard to imagine how to explain this in enough detail without writing most of the script itself for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The "wrapper function" is to let *other people* test an answer. Ideally, you would have included one in your question itself as part of making a [mcve], so people who don't have `yum` can write answers, and people who don't have `yum` can *test* those answers. Just replace `write_output` with your `yum` command when you want to run the code in a real-world (non-QA-based) environment.

Comment: ...I've amended to demonstrate how to replace the wrapper with your real command. I'm certainly not going to remove the wrapper -- if I did so, nobody but you could test the answer's correctness (I couldn't either!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first, so people who don't have `yum` can test this, let's make a wrapper function:

```
write_output() { cat <<EOF
Repo-id: wazuh_repo
Repo-name: Wazuhrepository
Repo-status: enabled
Repo-revision: 1536348945
Repo-updated: FriSep712:35:512018
Repo-pkgs: 73
Repo-size: 920M
Repo-baseurl: https://packages.wazuh.com/3.x/yum/
Repo-expire: 21,600second(s)(last:WedOct3108:59:002018)
EOF
}
```

Notably, all your keys come before the string `:`, and the values come after them -- so we want to read line-by-line, split based on colon-space sequences, treat what was in front as a key, and treat what's in back as a value.

---

Given that:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs | split(": ")] | reduce .[] as $kv ({}; .[$kv[0]] = $kv[1])' < <(write_output)
```

...properly emits:

```
{
  "Repo-id": "wazuh_repo",
  "Repo-name": "Wazuhrepository",
  "Repo-status": "enabled",
  "Repo-revision": "1536348945",
  "Repo-updated": "FriSep712:35:512018",
  "Repo-pkgs": "73",
  "Repo-size": "920M",
  "Repo-baseurl": "https://packages.wazuh.com/3.x/yum/",
  "Repo-expire": "21,600second(s)(last:WedOct3108:59:002018)"
}
```

---

...so, how does that work?

- `jq -R` turns on *raw input* mode; input is parsed as a sequence of raw strings, not as a sequence of JSON documents.
- `jq -n` treats `null` as the only direct input, so one can then use `input` and `inputs` primitives inside the script where needed.
- `[ inputs ]` reads all your lines of input, and puts them into a single array.
- `[ inputs | split(": ")]` changes that from an array of strings to an array of lists -- with content both before and after the `": "` sequence.
- `reduce .[] as $kv ( {}; ... )` starts a *reducer*, with an initial value of `{}`, and then feeds each value that `.[]` evaluates to (which is to say, each item in your list) into that reducer (the `...` code) as the `$kv` variable, replacing the `.` value each time.

---

To run this with your yum command as the real input, change `< <(write_output)` to `< <(yum -v repolist all | grep -B2 -A6 "enabled" | sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' , 's/--//g' , 's/name=name=/name=/g')`.

Comment: You can compact it down a bit more: `reduce (inputs | split(": ")) as [$k, $v] ({}; .[$k] = $v)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more robust variation of @CharlesDuffy's answer.  Since the latter provides excellent explanatory notes, further explanations are not given here.

```
jq -nR '
  [inputs | index(": ") as $ix | {(.[:$ix]): .[$ix+2:]}]
  | add'
```

This avoids using `split` in case the "value" contains ": ".  It might, however, be still better not to assume that a space follows the first relevant ":".

Notice also that `add` is used here instead of `reduce`, solely for compactness and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

For these sorts of problems, I would prefer to use a regular expression to match keys and values. Otherwise, I would take an approach similar to Charles's.

```
$ ... | jq -Rn 'reduce (inputs | capture("(?<k>[^:]+):\\s*(?<v>.+)")) as {$k, $v} ({}; .[$k] = $v)'
```